# 1/(2^n)! is negligible function?

Tags: provable-security

By definition $\frac {1} {n}$, $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\frac{1}{n!}$ are negligible functions.

I have got the function  $$f(n) = \frac{1}{(2^n)!}$$ where $n$ is security parameter.

I don't understand, How do I formally proof that $$\frac{1}{(2^n)!}$$ is a negligible function? Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You may want to note that $1/n$ is _not_ a negligible function because $1/n^2$ approaches $0$ much faster...

Comment: Start with the definition of negligible function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negligible function defined as product of polynomial and a negligible function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54240/negligible-function-defined-as-product-of-polynomial-and-a-negligible-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to prove a function $f$ is negligible if it is *obviously* negligible is to show that it is "more negligible" than some other function $g$ which you have already proven negligble, e.g. $g(n)=2^{-n}$.

Because $g$ is negligble, there exists $n_{g_0}$ such that for all $n>n_{g_0}$ it holds that $g(n)<1/{n^c}$ for any fixed choice of $c$.

Now you can capitalize on that by showing that there exists some $n_{f_0}$ such that for all $n>n_{f_0}$ it holds that $f(n)\leq g(n)$. Clearly it then holds that for all $n>\max(n_{f_0},n_{g_0})$ that $f(n)\leq g(n)<1/n^c$ which means $f$ is negligible.

I'll leave the choice of $g$ for your concrete application to you.

Comment: I, usually, find the [limit definition](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63310/18298) much easier to play.